# Form not appearing on Adminhtml

Tags: adminhtml, blocks, adminform

Here's my folder structure for my block:

```
Product
| - Form.php
Product.php
```

My product form is a Form Container which is supposed to launch the Form stored within Product -> Form.php

However, although `Product.php` is loading fine, the `Product -> Form.php` does not seem to be appearing. I have a simple form setup, with a simple field on there asking for a Product SKU. The Fieldset nor the form it's contained within are loading on the page.

```
<?php
/**
 * Form for Warehouse Products.
 * Loads individual items that make up the form itself.
 *
 * @author Dan Hanly
 **/
class Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Warehouse_Edit_Product_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    public $_id;        // Identifier of the block
    public $_title;     // Title of the block
    public $_form;      // Varien_Data_Form

    /**
     * Init class
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_id = 'product_form';
        $this->_title = $this->__('Product Information');
    }

    /**
     * Setup form fields for inserts/updates
     *
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
     * @author Dan Hanly
     */
    public function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = Mage::registry('module_warehouse');
        $request = $this->getRequest();

        $this->_form = $this->createForm($this->getUrl('*/*/save', $this->getUrlParameters($request)));
        $this->setForm($this->_form);

        $fieldset = $this->_form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array(
            'legend' => $this->_title,
            'class' => 'fieldset-wide',
        ));

        if ($this->isEdit($request)) {
            $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', array(
                'name' => 'id',
            ));
        }

        $fieldset->addField('warehouse_id', 'hidden', array(
            'name' => 'warehouse_id',
            'value' => Mage::registry('module_warehouse')->getId()
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('product_id', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'product_id',
            'label' => $this->__('Choose Product'),
            'value' => $this->__('Choose Product'),
        ));

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
```

There's nothing relevant in the logs that would allude to this.

**EDIT**
I clarified my question to strip out parts that were irrelevant.

Comment: show your layout file ?

Comment: I'm not using one. This is all instantiated through code. For reference, every other edit form on the site works as expected, except when trying to load this one. It's something specific about this block.

Comment: I think it's something to do with the fact that it's an edit form, effectively within another edit form.

Comment: I am not getting your point. A form has tabs.  YouR  tab working, but form is not working. how?

Comment: Within the Product (Edit->Tabs->Product) tab, there is a button to 'Add Products' to the Warehouse. That button launches a modal view which loads the Edit Product block. It's a standard Form Container which in-turn, loads Edit Product Form. I know the Edit Product Block is working, as it's displaying the title etc. However, the Edit Product Form Block isn't displaying at all.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved the issue.

Essentially, Magento automatically looks for a Form Container's Form within an Edit folder.
So as my Form was stored within the Product folder, it wasn't displaying.

There is a class variable in the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container` class called `$this->_mode`. This variable defaults to `'edit'` - this alone influences the form container's search for a class in the Edit folder.

Within my form container class, I was able to override the _mode variable, providing `'product'` as it's value. Now, everything is connected up as it should be.